# Is this generalization of differentiable manifolds to mixed dimensions a known object?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, parabolic-pde

Suppose you are studying the evolution of some electromagnetic quantity in a conductor consisting of objects of several dimensions, i.e. wires, plates and balls.
This would amount to studying the evolution of some PDE on a manifold that mixes different dimensions.

I was wondering if the following approach to defining and studying such objects is known. I suspect the answer is yes but I couldn't find a reference.
I won't be perfectly rigorous here as I haven't nailed down all details and in defining differentiable manifolds there is a bunch of busywork which I suppose ome can reasonable imagine.

We define a multufold as a topological space where each point has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to some subset of R^n (with possibly regularity requirements) (n may vary along the manifold).

We now add a $C^\infty$ structure as a collection of charts $(U,\phi)$ as usual.
Suppose that $\phi: U \longrightarrow R^n$ and $\psi: V \longrightarrow R^m$ are two charts around a point $p$. Then there exist open sets $A \supseteq \phi(U \cap V)$ and $ B \supseteq \psi(U \cap V)$ as well as a $C^\infty$ map from $A$ to $B$ that extends $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$.
You get the idea.

Then we can define tangent spaces as scale invariant subsets of finite vector spaces of equivalence classes of curves.
If we add the equivalent of a metric wecan consider the Hausdorff measure.
Given some assumption that the Hausdorff dimension is stable in a small neighbourhood around each point (for every smaller neighbourhood it is the same), we get a natural measure om the manifold which is given by the Hausdorff measure of correct dimension locally.

Consider as an example a line intersection a closed half plane in two dimensional space. On the line we have the one dimensional Hausdorff and on the plane the two dim3nsional one. An initial distribution of heat on the line evolving undet the heat equation will spread into the plane. This requires some way of converting "linear kinetic energy density"  to "quadratic kinetic energy density". The way we define the heat flow should use that we have measures of correct dimension on each part to make this happen naturally.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem with such an approach is that a "manifold with mixed dimensions" always has locally constant dimension, i.e. every connected component will be a manifold in the classical sense. In particular: There are no points where a 1-dimensional "wire" touches a 3-dimensional "ball" etc. to conduct heat between the two. The reason is that the topology at such connecting points is not locally euclidean.

Comment: It may be more practical to not consider connecting points at all and model your situation as a bunch of ordinary manifolds (with boundary) and treat the connecting points between them as separate heat sources & sinks, i.e. the point where a heated wire touches a ball get translated into a heat sink at the end of the wire and a (point-like) heat source at the boundary of the ball.

Comment: There are various situations where such objects appear in symplectic geometry. There are various models for such things. Things you could look into are: polyfolds, Kuranishi atlasses, Diffeological spaces, derived geometry, ...

Comment: @JohannesHahn: it took me a while to figure out, but the OP allows the neighborhood to map to **arbitrary** subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which are not necessarily open. (Which is why in the chart construction the OP requires open sets that cover $\phi(U\cap V)$ etc.) In particular, in the OP's definition, **any** subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a multufold.

Comment: @WillieWong Oh, I didn't see that. Of course, if one allows (almost) arbitrary point clouds  and fractals as the underlying spaces etc, then one has opened a whole different can of worms. And I'd guess that saying anything useful at all about PDEs on these spaces very quickly becomes very hard work.

Comment: A random and imprecise thought: let's concentrate just on the example you had in mind. Let $L$ be the non-positive real axis and $H$ be the right half plane. I think $L\cup H$ can be given the structure of a metric measure space: use the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and I think for any $\alpha,\beta > 0$, you can define $\mu_{\alpha,\beta}(A) = \alpha \lambda_1(L\cap A) + \beta \lambda_2(H\cap A)$ ($\lambda_1$ is the one dimensional Lebesgue measure on $L$, and $\lambda_2$ the two dimensional Lebesgue measure on $H$).

Comment: For heat equations, there exists literature on the study of diffusion processes on general metric measure spaces. So maybe for the case you are specifically thinking of there is a way out that doesn't strictly require defining a multufold.

Comment: Several authors (Lang, Tu) define manifolds so that variable dimension is allowed. This is useful in the context of study of group actions as fixed point set might be manifolds of mixed dimension.

Comment: Spaces modelled in arbitrary subsets of Euclidean spaces, where one tries to still do some meaningful differential geometry (differentiable functions, vector fields, flows, etc.), bring to mind subcartesian spaces, a particular kind of Sikorski spaces (also called differential spaces). 
If it is fine to restrict to spaces locally modelled on closed subsets of euclidean spaces (as objects made of wires, plates, balls likely are) then you could look at differentiable spaces (something like a particularly nice differential geometric scheme), which may be easier to manage.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: But Lang's definition (I'm looking at "Fundamentals of DG") implies that the dimension is constant on any connected component, which seems to be more restrictive than what the OP is looking at.

Comment: @WillieWong: I see. I misunderstood OP's question (I was assuming that $U$ is open). I do not see how OP's setup can be possibly useful unless some stronger assumptions on the domains $U$ of OP's charts are introduced.